# Arguments in Functions

Tags: python, function, arguments

This is the code:

```
list = [1,2,3]

def func(index):
  return 'list[' + index + ']'
func('0')
```

When I call the **function**, it returns a string: `'list[0]'` but I want it to return the value of the list in index `[0]` which is `1`. 
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `list[int(index)]`? If you want a value, why build a string?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it overwrites the constructor for the `list` type and can lead to hard to debug errors and other issues. I'd also recommend having your function take a `list` object as an argument in addition to the desired index. Then simply return `input_list[index]`, assuming `index` is an `int`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so parenthesis are used. I used brackets`{index}`. Anyways thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to expect that the `return` statement will evaluate a string as if it were a Python expression and return the result. It won't. Now, there is a way to achieve that in Python but it is *almost never a good idea* and is needed far less often than beginners tend to imagine. This will do what you want: `return list[int(index)]` but is going to fail several code quality tests. 1. `list` is not a good variable name. 2. `func()` depends on a global variable for no good reason: pass all the data the function needs to it as parameters, as in `def func(index,mylist):.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3]

def func(index,list1):
    return list1[int(index)]
res=func('0',list1 )
print(res)
# 1
```